# Gradient Boosting Positive/Negative feature importance in python

Tags: classification, python, boosting, importance

I am using gradient boosting to predict feature  importance for a classification problem where one class is success and other is failed. However my model is only predicting feature importance for positive class. Can someone assist to predict feature importance of  both positive and negative class.
**Sample data**
[image]

```
# code that I used for above feature importance                         
 x.columns = \[x.lower() for x in x.columns\] gb=
GradientBoostingClassifier(learning_rate= 0.1, max_depth=
 4,n_estimators=500, max_features = 0.9,min_samples_leaf = 2)
 x.columns = [x.lower() for x in x.columns]

feature_importance = gb.feature_importances_
# make importances relative to max importance
#feature_importance = 100.0 * (feature_importance / feature_importance.max())
sorted_idx = np.argsort(feature_importance)
pos = np.arange(sorted_idx.shape[0]) + .5
# plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
#colors=['o','b','g','y','k','#66b3ff','#99ff99','#ff9999']
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.barh(pos, feature_importance[sorted_idx], align='center',color=colors)
plt.yticks(pos, x.keys()[sorted_idx])
plt.xlabel('Relative Importance')
plt.title('Variable Importance for Gradient Boost',fontsize=15)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome Kipkogei Francis! The prediction step should normally provide you with two columns each with one predicted value for each class. If you provide a sample of your data and the code you have tried then it may be possible to solve your problem otherwise only general comments are possible.

Comment: Balance classes?

Comment: Classes are imbalanced , but the model evaluation metrics performs better than balanced one

Comment: Are you using a model selection criterion or an error metric?

Comment: Hello EngrStudent, Am using model selection criterion

Comment: When you only have two classes, there is no way to identify a feature as being "important" for one class vs the other; a feature is important if it helps _distinguish_ the two classes.